# GUI does not show up in GAE environment but works fine in my local environment

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-app-engine, processing

I'm working on a side project to implement a simple web game and want to host it on Google App Engine(GAE). I've done a version, and tested it my local machine(Ubuntu 14.04) to make sure everything's fine. Then, I deploy to GAE but it just show me a blank page. I use inspect in Chrome browser and found the page was loaded, but it just behave differently with my local environment.

I uploaded my source code to [github](https://github.com/shincar/WinstonsNOhnoes_v2). Could someone also using GAE could help to check anything weired?

Regards,
Adam

Comment: In GAE you should change to 80 port.

Comment: You have mentioned port:8080 under env_variables. Why so? While deploying on GAE your project will have a url.

Comment: I just randomly pick a port. I changed port to 80 and deploy again but it still doesn't work. Noticed that when I assigned port to 8080, I saw record page showing "server listening at port 8080" and the page could be correctly requested. I use "Inspect" tool and saw the whole source. When I assigned port to 80, I saw record  page showing "server listening at port 8081 and the page can't be loaded successfully. Any other suggestion?

Comment: I finally found the issue. It's because I'm using @pjs preload to load images and some how the image can't be loaded in GAE's environment. The first way I did is to host those images at different site, e.g. github pages. More proper way would be add handlers in app.yaml to point to correct path images should be loaded as [this page](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/config/appref#handlers_element) described.